# Buscar todos métodos sem referencia Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, análise-estática

Como buscar todos os métodos sem referencia no Visual Studio, ou seja, métodos que não estão sendo utilizados, sei que ao clicar em um método com o botão direito e escolher "Find All References" ele mostra as referências, como fazer para todos da *solution*?

Comment: Com "sem referência" tu quer dizer "não utilizado"?

Comment: Muito útil para trabalhar com sistemas legados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Visual Studio padrão não tem como, mas existem utilitários para instalar nele que podem ajudar.

No [FXCop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6544&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) existem algumas regras que detectam isto, especialmente a

> Private methods that are not called from any other code (CA1811)

Ela não resolve tudo, mas faz o mais óbvio. Se tem algo público que não foi usado precisa pensar porque não foi usado, talvez possa ser um dia. Eu não sairia limando estes métodos tão facilmente, muito menos os usaria só para ter uso.

O [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) pode fazer uma busca na solução toda. Na solução procure por `Find Code Issues` E depois `Unused Symbols`. Vai buscar não só métodos não usados.

Também pode ir em `ReSharper` => `Inspect` => `Codes Issues` Depois vai em `Filter Issues` e lá selecione  `Redundancy in Symbol Ddeclaration` => `type or type member is never use`.

Tem ainda o [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). Tem que criar uma consulta, tem [exemplo no site](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html).